# Help with count();

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got 2 tables. 
One called Video,  and one called ThumbsUp.

```
Video    -> Id, Path, Thumbnail, Profile

ThumbsUp -> Id, Owner, Video
```

I need to pull every Video record `WHERE PROFILE = 2`, 
And `COUNT(ThumbsUp.Id)` the number of likes for each video, 
Even if that video does not have any thumbs up.

Any help is appreciated. . .

Comment: How both tables are related each to other? By which column? Can't believe that by Id column because each row should has own unique Id, I expect to see something like VideoId for ThumbsUp but dont see

Comment: Tables are related by Video.Id and ThumbsUp.Video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Video.Id, COUNT(ThumbsUp.Video) 
FROM 
  Video LEFT JOIN ThumbsUp ON Video.Id = ThumbsUp.Video
WHERE Video.Profile = 2
GROUP BY Video.Id
```

Comment: Each table will have its own unique id for each row, so Video.Id and ThumbsUp.Id have no relation.

Comment: Thanks Michael & Hunter, you guys are the best. I was banging my head against a wall forever... the whole time I was grouping by ThumbsUp.Id. Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT v.*, count(tu.id) 
      FROM video v 
      LEFT JOIN ThumbsUp tu ON tu.video_id = v.id 
  WHERE v.profile = 2
  GROUP BY v.id
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT V.*, COUNT(T.id) FROM Video V
OUTER JOIN ThumbsUp T ON T.Video = V.id
WHERE V.profile == 2;
```

Edit: added outer join

Comment: what is the relation between video and thumbsup ?

Comment: Won't give zero ThumbsUp counts or even group the Videos

Comment: Anyway there is should be OUTER join to suffice requirement

Comment: the relationship is in T.video = v.id, the join is wrong, my mistake